# How can I check if QPdfWriter object can write to the specified file?

Tags: qt, object, exists

I am creating the PDF documents in Qt using command:

```
QPdfWriter *pdf;
pdf = new QPdfWriter(filename);
```

Sometimes the object is not created due to a wrong filename or document exists and is open in other application...

How can I check if object was created (if the pdf pointer points to the valid object)?

EDIT: My mistake was, that object is not created. It is not true. The QPdfWriter object is created, but there is no exception or error generated.
I can set some properties.
The problem will occur later when I am trying to write something to the document - see comments of the last 3 commands:

```
pdf->setParent(this);
pdf->setPageSize(QPdfWriter::A4);
pdf->setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Orientation::Landscape);
QPainter *p = new QPainter(pdf); //got message: QPainter::begin(): Returned false
ui->chartView->render(p); // no error
p->end(); // got message: QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

I read the documentation of [QpdfWriter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpdfwriter.html) and parent classes [QPagedPaintDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpagedpaintdevice.html) and [QPaintDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html#paintingActive). I cannot find any property/method to check if I can write to the document...

So question - how to check if I can write to the document?

Comment: You have misunderstood something. `new` will always return a valid pointer to a constructed object, *or* throw an exception. Since this is Qt, which doesn't really use exceptions, latter case is probably out. `pdf` will be a pointer to a valid `QPdfWriter` instance. So what you want to ask is "how do I check if `QPdfWrtier` opened the file successfully?" I'm sure the documentation tells how to check for errors, but if not, please clarify your question about what exactly is the issue with checking if there was an error.

Comment: @hyde, thanks to this hint. Yes, object is created, but there is no error or exception generated. I edited my question.

Comment: You could try with this constructor, so you could create the file first using QFile and check that it's ok afterwards: QPdfWriter::QPdfWriter(QIODevice *device)

Answer (score 2):

Ive just stumpled over the same issue, the hint with `bool QFileInfo::isWritable() const` didn't do the trick for me. Though you basically gave the answer yourself with the comment on the third last command, with the return value of `QPainter::begin()` you can check if the `QPdfWriter` can generate the pdf.

```
QPainter *p = new QPainter;
if (p->begin(pdf)) { 
    ui->chartView->render(p); 
    p->end();
} else {
    // error message...
}
```